# Java show fullscreen swing application with taskbar without titlebar

Tags: java, swing

I need to develop a full-screen GUI without a title bar on it (I am going to use border layout design page start as my own title), also need to show the taskbar. I have tried this:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Frame becomes full-screen without the title bar but hides the taskbar.

if I change to  `frame.setUndecorated(false);` 
the frame becomes full-screen and taskbar is shown, but title bar doesn't disappear

How can I fix that? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works for one desktop

```
    Rectangle r = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setSize(r.width, r.height);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Edit: Works for multiple desktops too!